# concatenating two vectors of different types loses information

Tags: c++, vector

I want to conjunction two vectors, but when I try to write result on the screen I get result without int number, which is in Two. I want to get result: one two three four 50
Can you help me, how to fix it? Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


template<typename T>
class One
{
protected:
    T word;
    T word2;

public:
    One() {word = "0"; word2 = "0";}
    One(T w, T w2) {word = w; word2 = w2;}
    virtual const void Show() {cout << word << endl; cout << word2 << endl;}
};

template<typename T>
class Two : public One<T>
{
protected:
    int number;
public:
    Two() {number = 0;}
    Two(T w, T w2, int n) : One(w,w2) {number = n;}
    virtual const void Show () {cout << word << endl; cout << word2 << endl; cout << number << endl; }
};


int main ()
{
    vector<One<string>> x;
    vector<Two<string>> x2;

    One<string> css("one","two");
    Two<string> csss("three","four",50);

    x.push_back(css);
    x2.push_back(csss);

    x.insert(x.end(),x2.begin(),x2.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
    {
        x.at(i).Show();
    }

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read about [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Comment: Read this: [What is the slicing problem in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments for "slicing". If you use pointers you'll get past this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


template<typename T>
class One
{
protected:
    T word;
    T word2;

public:
    One() {word = "0"; word2 = "0";}
    One(T w, T w2) {word = w; word2 = w2;}
    virtual const void Show() {cout << word << endl; cout << word2 << endl;}
};

template<typename T>
class Two : public One<T>
{
protected:
    int number;
public:
    Two() {number = 0;}
    Two(T w, T w2, int n) : One(w,w2) {number = n;}
    virtual const void Show () {cout << word << endl; cout << word2 << endl; cout << number << endl; }
};


int main ()
{
    std::vector< One<string> * > x;
    std::vector< Two<string> * > x2;

    One<string> css("one","two");
    Two<string> csss("three","four",50);

    x.push_back(&css);
    x2.push_back(&csss);

    x.insert(x.end(),x2.begin(),x2.end());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
    {
        x.at(i)->Show();
    }

    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are suffering from a problem called slicing.

The problem is that vector `x` can only store objects of type `One<string>`.
When you insert objects of type `Two<string>` the object is sliced on copy (because when you put things into a vector they are copied in). So Basically you copy an object of type `Two<string>` into a location that can only hold a `One<String>` thus you are loosing the extra information (it is sliced off).

```
 // Example:
 Two<string>    two("plop","plop1",34);
 two.show;

 One<string>    one("stop","stop1");
 one.show;

 one = two;    // copy a two into a one.
 one.show;   // Notice no number this time.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not polymorphism which is expect by you

```
x.at(i).Show();
```

Simply you're calling `Show` of `One`. You're not calling the method `Show` of class `Two`,